# How to set the constraints of dynamic scaffolding project?

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm very new to grails web application! Here is my domain class

```
package imocha.project

class Feedback {
    String name
    String email
    String type
    String remark

    static constraints = {
      name(blank:true)
      email(blank:true)
      type(blank:false)
      remark(blank:false)
    }
}
```

In my case, I just want to set only the type and remark can't be blank! But at the end, it set all for me.

[image: Display adding screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the default behavior for properties is `nullable: false` in a Grails project. Alter your constraints as follows:

```
package imocha.project

class Feedback {
    String name
    String email
    String type
    String remark

    static constraints = {
      name(nullable:true, blank:true)
      email(nullable:true, blank:true)
      type(blank:false)
      remark(blank:false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Negative, still remain same

Comment: stop your project, run a `clean` and try again.

Comment: Still same, is it something wrong with the gsp in view?

Comment: Problem solved! I regenerated the controller and views code with your answer, it works perfectly